# Unable to use Keyvault Secrets to do Domain Join

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to join a domain using a scripted process where the Username and password are hidden.

I thought using Keyvault in Azure would be the best way, however when I use the below script it gives me some errors. Is this possible, or am I going about this the wrong way.

These are Azure VMs

```
$AdminUser = 'https://<Keyvault>.vault.azure.net:443/secrets/AdminUser/de7d74df74ff4099b0bd7422c171a4fe'
$AdminPassName = 'https://<Keyvault>.vault.azure.net:443/secrets/SQLPassword/f394ded0cc16482096bc181f5ab650bd'

$mycred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$($AdminUser.SecretValueText)", $AdminPass.SecretValue)

$domain = 'hmr.loc'

Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $mycred
```

the error I get is

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot process argument because the value of argument "userName" is not valid. Change the value of the 
"userName" argument and run the operation again."
At line:1 char:11
+ $mycred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$($A ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I think its to do with this line...

```
$mycred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$($AdminUser.SecretValueText)", $AdminPass.SecretValue)
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach doesnt make sense (idea does). You need to perform rest calls to the the secret URI, not just declare the uri and use it as a variable. So you generally have 2 approaches:

1. Perform rest call yourself (you will have to handle auth yourself in that case)
2. Use powershell cmdlet to retrive Key Vault Secret, but you will need to authenticate to Azure first with sufficient rights to perform this call

Either way you will have to pass in some data you will use to authenticate, so you probably need to take a step back and use your higher level scripts\entities to handle that for you and securely pass user\password to your script.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense, I would need the modules and I'm assigning the variables with the URI, not the username\password. Thanks for the feedback :)